# Splitting Goole-Play-Scraper Results

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a React front-end with a Node back-end, and all I'm trying to do is scrape some data from the Google Play Store using Facundo Olano's [Google-Play-Scraper](https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper#app).

This is my React front-end...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';

export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        title: '',
        review: ''
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.callApi()
            .then(res => this.setState({
                title: res.title,
                review: res.review
            }))
            .catch(err => console.log('Error: ', err));
    }

    callApi = async () => {
        const response = await fetch('/gPlay');
        const body = await response.json();

        if (response.status !== 200) {
            throw Error(body.message);
        }

        return body;
    };

    render() {
        console.log("==================== app log ====================");
        console.log("State: ", this.state);
        return (
            <div className="App">

                <p>Title: {this.state.title}.</p>
                <p>Review: {this.state.review}.</p>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is my Node back-end...

```
[const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT||5000;

const gPlay = require('google-play-scraper');
const appToScrape = 'com.mojang.minecraftpe';

app.get('/gPlay', (req, res) => {
    const gPlayResults = gPlay.app({appId: appToScrape});

    console.log('==================== server log ====================');
    gPlayResults.then(console.log);

    res.send({
        title: 'title',
        review: 'review',
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}`));
```

This is a small snippet of the results i'm getting...

```
{
price: 6.99,
free: false,
currency: 'USD',
priceText: '$6.99',
offersIAP: true,
size: 'Varies with device'
}
```

I'm getting the full results as per the doc's, but I need to be able to split the returned object up to be able to send bits of it back to the front-end, but I can't for the life of me get it to work.

I thought I could just simply do something like `gPlayResults.price` and have 6.99 returned, but all that comes back is undefined.

Please can someone help, I must be missing something as it surely can't be that hard!?

Thanks xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I worked it out! :)

For anyone who's interested, `gPlayResults` is being assigned a `Promise` and not the object I was expecting.

I made a callback using **`.then`** and was able to use the result I needed to send a usable object back to the front end.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const googlePlayApp = require('google-play-scraper');
const appToScrape = 'com.mojang.minecraftpe';

app.get('/gPlay', (req, res) => {
    console.log('==================== /gPlay ====================');
    const gPlayResults = googlePlayApp.app({appId: appToScrape});

    gPlayResults.then(function(result) {
        res.send({
            appObject: result
        })
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}`));
```

On to the next problem...